# Ionic cordova not install app in emulate android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I need help to fix on a bug in my ionic. I want to emulate my app in android. This is the result of my *ionic info*:

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)          : 4.1.2 (/usr/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework            : @ionic/angular 4.0.0-beta.7
   @angular-devkit/core       : 0.7.5
   @angular-devkit/schematics : 0.7.5
   @angular/cli               : 6.1.5
   @ionic/ng-toolkit          : 1.0.8
   @ionic/schematics-angular  : 1.0.6

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.0.0
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.1.4, (and 4 other plugins)

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/home/abner/android-sdk-linux)
   NodeJS            : v10.11.0 (/usr/bin/node)
   npm               : 5.6.0
   OS                : Linux 4.15
```

So when executing `ionic cordova emulate android -lc` I receive:

```
 [cordova]  Android Studio project detected
[cordova]  ANDROID_HOME=/home/abner/android-sdk-linux
[cordova]  JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
[cordova]  studio
[cordova]  Subproject Path: CordovaLib
[cordova]  Subproject Path: app
[cordova]  publishNonDefault is deprecated and has no effect anymore. All variants are now published.
[cordova]  The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.
[cordova]   at build_6sluibrwve5th57ipzalrhlh5.run(/home/abner/Documentos/work/app-cidadao-itaparica/platforms/android/app/build.gradle:143)
[cordova]  Configuration 'compile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead.
[cordova]  :CordovaLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE

... 
[cordova]  BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2s
[cordova]  46 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 42 up-to-date
[cordova]  Built the following apk(s): 
[cordova]   /home/abner/Documentos/work/app-cidadao-itaparica/platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
[cordova]  ANDROID_HOME=/home/abner/android-sdk-linux
[cordova]  JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
[cordova]  No emulator specified, defaulting to Pixel_XL_API_26
[cordova]  Waiting for emulator to start...
[ng] Date: 2018-09-28T13:54:10.217Z
[ng] Hash: f3e0f41853901b386e01
[ng] Time: 13004ms
[ng] chunk {common} common.js, common.js.map (common) 8.67 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {129} 129.js, 129.js.map () 14.9 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {cordova} cordova.js, cordova.js.map (cordova) 73.2 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {0} 0.js, 0.js.map () 46 kB  [rendered]
...
[ng] chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 15.5 kB [initial] [rendered]
[ng] chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 227 kB [initial] [rendered]
[ng] chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 8.06 kB [entry] [rendered]
[ng] chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 36 kB [initial] [rendered]
[ng] chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 4.26 MB [initial] [rendered]
[ng] chunk {126} 126.js, 126.js.map () 1.03 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {127} 127.js, 127.js.map () 3.49 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {128} 128.js, 128.js.map () 7.29 kB  [rendered]
[ng] ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
```

My android AVD manager opens normality but the ionic not install the app. I need help. How I may execute correctly ionic cordova emulate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still not resolve this problem, but I was able to run the app uninstalling android oreo and installing android 7.1.1, change Cordova platform 7.0.0 to 6.4.0. Life goes on! :)